# Fancybox 3: How to dynamically adjust the height of iframe when preload: false

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

I am testing Fancybox 3 to see how the iframe's height can be dynamically adjusted based on the actual content. Here is what I have:

```
<a class="iframe-link" data-type="iframe" href="/page-mini.html" >
    iframe
</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe-link").fancybox({
        iframe: {
            preload: false 
        },
        afterLoad : function(instance, slide) {
           slide.$slide.find('iframe').on('load', function() {
              instance.update(); 
           });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This code is not working. I have to use `preload: false` for better user experience and to be able to dynamically adjust the height because inside the frame I will show a few pages of different height. the page-mini.html is just a few lines of text.

Comment: Could you, please, explain why you think that this would make "better user experience"? I believe that it would be just opposite - you would initially show iframe at some random dimensions and then, after it loads completely, it would suddenly resize and recenter. That would look just weird and annoying and fancybox was designed to solve this issue.

Comment: Janis, by better user expereince, I mean the height matches actual content. I totally understand the sudden "resize and recenter". Can the height of the iframe be adjusted automatically by Fancybox or can I do it via javascript? I have to do `preload: false`, which makes loading seemingly super faster. Thanks!

Comment: Janis, you may be able to answer this question. If I buy one license of Fancybox 3, can I use it on my development machine AND only one website on the internet? They are about the same project. I really hope to be able to first address the need for dynamically adjustng iframe height. I am not able find support email at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Comment: Yes, you can use on same project. To make your snippet work, you would have to manually calculate and set dimensions (for iframe parent element) before calling 'instance.update();'. I give up fighting spam and chose to use Twitter and gitter.im instead.

Comment: Janis, can I use the same license for Fancybox 2 first and later migrate to Fancybox 3 for the same project? Regards.

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: Hello Janis, I bought a single site license. May I know the version of the Fancybox 3? Thanks for the great work and help!

Comment: Hi, If you have so many questions, then better use https://gitter.im/fancyapps/fancybox You can find info about all releases on GitHub https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/releases